# Computer not booting from DVD

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot, dvd, iso-image

I have a dell precision t3500 with windows 7 and am currently trying to dual-boot ubuntu Linux 16.04.3 from a DVD. However, the computer won't recognize it during boot-up and automatically goes to windows. I've checked that the computer can read the DVD, that CDs are first in the boot order, that the ISO is bootable and even pulled the power out after restarting to make sure that it was completely rebooting. Has anyone had similar problems or know of a solution?
P.S. There is also 50+ GBs of unallocated space.

Comment: Are you facing this issue with a particular DVD or are you not able to boot from any boot disks. I know you mentioned that the computer can read from the DVD but in my opinion it's best to check with other boot disks as well to be sure that it's not an issue with the optical media.

Comment: I've tried with another Ubuntu disk, and had the same problems.

Comment: And are you able to boot from that disk on a different computer?

Comment: How did you burn that DVD exactly?